# MySQL join with max date where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Hope someone may help me...
I have 2 tables which master detail with pinjid column as the corelation,

table 1: pinjaman

```js
pinjid   nilai  jasa
1        100    10
2        200    20
3        400    40
4        500    50
```

table 2: transaksi_detail

```js
id  pinjid   tanggal        pokok  t_jasa
1   1        2018-02-01  100    10    
2   2        2018-02-05  100    10    
3   1        2018-02-11  30     3  
4   3        2018-02-18  200    20  
5   3        2018-02-20  60     6  
6   2        2018-02-21  70     7
```

I need to merge both table or make a view to display the following data.

```js
pinjid   nilai  jasa    pokok     t_jasa
1        100    10      30        3      
2        200    20      70        7
3        400    40      60        6
3        500    50      0         0
```

Data teken from transaki_detail is the newest date and group by pinjid. 
With following query, data from transaksi_detail table is not the newest date.

```js
SELECT p.pinjid AS pinjid,
  p.anggota AS anggota,
  p.nilai_pinjam AS nilai_pinjam,
  p.nilai_jasa AS nilai_jasa,
  t.pokok AS pokok,
  t.jasa AS jasa,
  t.denda AS denda
FROM (pinjaman p
  CROSS JOIN transaksi_detail t)
GROUP BY p.pinjid
```

I know that probably i need to use max(tanggal) in where clause to get the data newest data, but i don't know how to implement it.

Comment: `SELECT p.pinjid AS pinjid,
  p.anggota AS anggota,
  p.nilai_pinjam AS nilai_pinjam,
  p.nilai_jasa AS nilai_jasa,
  t.pokok AS pokok,
  t.jasa AS jasa,
  t.denda AS denda.. GROUP BY p.pinjid` is a invalid SQL query. And will result in bad unrelated selected data for the grouped p.pinjid  https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would `join` the tables and then filter to get the latest date.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT p.pinjid AS pinjid, p.anggota AS anggota, p.nilai_pinjam AS nilai_pinjam, p.nilai_jasa AS nilai_jasa,
       t.pokok AS pokok, t.jasa AS jasa, t.denda AS denda
FROM pinjaman p JOIN
     transaksi_detail t
     ON p.pinjid = t.pinjid
WHERE t.tanggal = (SELECT MAX(t2.tanggal)
                   FROM transaksi_detail t2
                   WHERE t2.pinjid = t.pinjid
                  );
```

Comment: @user1991131 . . . Is there a reason why you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: Apologized, i just double check my detail table content and it was my mistake.